# How to pass nifti (.nii) files to tensorflow for neural network training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have 3d mri images stored as nifti(.nii) files. Upon some online search i found that each nifti file when extracted contain 256 images, each representing capture of the brain from a different position on x,y and z axis rotation.

**My Attempt:**

In order to pass it to a neural network i red each nifti file as a numpy array. Each individual image was of `193 x 256` dimension, since one nifti file contained 256 images, the dimension of each nifti file converted into a numpy array were `193 x 256 x 256`.

```py
# a very small architecture to just make it work
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           input_shape=(193, 256, 256)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( ( images, labels ) )   # tf.constant() does not change error
dataset = dataset.batch(1)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=1)
```

**Problem:**

This leads into memory issues and the jupyter notebook dies no matter how small the neural network is. I'm not sure what to do keep to train the neural network on the 3d medical images.

I'd really appreciate if anyone could suggest a better way to train the neural on given 3d medical images

Comment: Could you please show the error code?

Comment: All jupyter notebook said was that it died, and the kernal restarted. It's an indication of Out of memory (OOM) as said by people online

Comment: @SyedHissaan, Did you tried to creates a .tfrecord file from a directory of nifti images ? sample code is [here](https://github.com/corticometrics/neuroimage-tensorflow/blob/master/genTFrecord.py) may resolve your issue.Thanks!